# Need to total column by only one of the multiple duplicate values...?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

Basically I only need the total of one value from GROSSWAGES per employee. 
I'm open to solutions on the SSRS side or on the data side. 
I can get the values I need if I do another dataset with distinct GROSSWAGES per employee, but it won't allow me to put data from two datasets into one matrix.

Here is an example of the data from the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    UPR00100.EMPLOYEEID
   ,UPR30300.PAYROLLCD
   ,UPR30300.AMOUNT
   ,UPR00900.GROSSWAGES
   ,CASE WHEN PAYROLLCD='401K' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS '401K'
   ,CASE WHEN PAYROLLCD='401KM' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS '401KM'
FROM    UPR00100 INNER JOIN
           UPR30300 ON UPR00100.EMPLOYEEID = UPR30300.EMPLOYEEID INNER JOIN
           UPR00900 ON UPR00100.EMPLOYEEID = UPR00900.EMPLOYEEID


EMPLOYEEID | PAYROLLCD | GROSSWAGES | AMOUNT   | 401K    | 401KM
00001      | 1S        | 12,500.00  | 7,500.00 |   0.00  |   0.00
00001      | 401K      | 12,500.00  |   375.00 | 375.00  |   0.00
00001      | 401KM     | 12,500.00  |   187.50 |   0.00  | 187.50
00002      | 1S        | 10,000.00  | 5,000.00 |   0.00  |   0.00
00002      | 401K      | 10,000.00  |   250.00 | 250.00  |   0.00
00002      | 401KM     | 10,000.00  |   125.50 |   0.00  | 125.00
```

When putting this data into a matrix on SSRS I need it to look like this:

```
EMPLOYEEID | GROSSWAGES | 401K    | 401KM
00001      | 12,500.00  | 375.00  | 187.50
00002      | 10,000.00  | 250.00  | 125.00
------------------------------------------
TOTAL      | 22,500.00  | 625.00  | 312.50
```

This is what I end up getting:

```
EMPLOYEEID | GROSSWAGES | 401K    | 401KM
00001      | 12,500.00  | 375.00  | 187.50
00002      | 10,000.00  | 250.00  | 125.00
------------------------------------------
TOTAL      | 67,500.00  | 625.00  | 312.50
```

Comment: seems that records duplicated because of PAYROLLCD is unique in select, but please provide samples for other tables, you've provided only one dataset example for UPR00100

Comment: Why not add another column for wages? `CASE WHEN PAYROLLCD = '1S' THEN GROSSWAGES ELSE 0 END AS TOTAL_WAGES`

Comment: @HannoverFist The reasoning for that is this report is ran for the month, and one employee would have two '1S' per month. I could do the same thing for a PAYROLLCD that is unique per month, but not all employees have the same PAYROLLCDs.

Comment: @VasilyIvoyzha I'm not sure I'm understanding what you are saying. I only used one dataset example because I cannot use data from two separate datasets in one visual/table/matrix. You want a sample of UPR00100, UPR30300, and UPR00900 individually?

Comment: Have you tried the `LOOKUP` function for using a second dataset?  It should be viable in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but you could try this...

For the employee group level rows, use

```
=AVG(Fields!GROSSWAGES.Value)
```

As the wages are always the same then the average will give you the same amount.

Then for the Total row use

```
=SUM(AVG(Fields!GROSSWAGES.Value, "myEmployeeRowGroupName"))
```

`myEmployeeRowGroupName` is just the name of the row group as seen in the grouping panels below the main design surface. It is case sensitive and must be in quotes.

The expression above will get the average for each instance in the scope (employee row group) and then sum the results.

This is off the top of my head and untested so you may have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: Awesome, that solved my issue! I didn't have to use an avg on the row (it did work, though) so I left it as normal, but the total expression gave me what I needed!